# Android Fastboot, infinite bootloop on phone

Tags: android, adb, android-automotive, fastboot

Good morning.

I have a linux machine with "Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS" version, "i7" with "32 GB ram".

I need to compile and flash an Android Automotive´s image in a "Pixel 5". I have followed [the official guide of Android](https://source.android.com/docs/automotive/start/pixelxl) step by step.

- First, download the last packets for Ubuntu with:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gnupg flex bison build-essential zip curl zlib1g-dev gcc-multilib g++-multilib libc6-dev-i386 libncurses5 lib32ncurses5-dev x11proto-core-dev libx11-dev lib32z1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libxml2-utils xsltproc unzip fontconfig
```

- After. Configure, sync and compile the repo (I have tried with multiple images, the last I tried it, was with "android-12.0.0_r11" / "SP1A.211105.004"):

```
mkdir aaos_on_phone
cd aaos_on_phone
git config --global user.name xxx
git config --global user.email xxx
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-12.0.0_r11 --use-superproject --partial-clone --partial-clone-exclude=platform/frameworks/base --clone-filter=blob:limit=10M
repo sync -j8 -c
```

The download and synchronize of repo works perfect without errors.

- Download the correct binary and propietary file for "android-12.0.0_r11" / "SP1A.211105.004" from [binary controller for Pixel](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers?hl=es-419) with:

```
curl --output - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/google_devices-redfin-sp1a.211105.004-7e165263.tgz  | tar -xzvf -
tail -n +315 extract-google_devices-redfin.sh | tar -zxvf -
curl --output - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/aosp/qcom-redfin-sp1a.211105.004-f5b84dcc.tgz?hl=es-419 | tar -xzvf -
tail -n +315 extract-qcom-redfin.sh | tar -xzvf -
```

- Compile for "redfin_car" and create the automotion package:

```
. build/envsetup.sh 
lunch aosp_redfin_car
m
m android.hardware.automotive.audiocontrol@1.0-service android.hardware.automotive.vehicle@2.0-service
```

- Configure "Pixel 5" with "OEM", debug by usb and transfer file.
- Before the next step, I have checked the "Pixel 5" with "lsusb", "adb", "fastboot" commands and it´s all ok. The device appears as attached.
  [ADB devices output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woV48.png)

All is correct till this step.

- Prepare the "Pixel 5" and update the compilation:

```
set "ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT" var with the folder where they are the img create in the previous steps ("out/target/product/redfin/").
adb reboot bootloader
sudo fastboot flashing unlock
sudo fastboot -w flashall
```

The problem comes here when I run "sudo fastboot -w flashall", the process starts and it stops after the output "Rebooting into fastboot"
[sudo fastboot -w flashall output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9SIO.png). In this step, the "Pixel 5" joins in an infinite loopboot (between bootloader and android screen) and I can´t follow with the next steps because "adb" doesn´t detect the device and I can´t send more "adb" command.

All help is wellcome. Thank you.

Comment: In fastboot mode adb never works, only `fastboot` command works then. The target phone is really a Pixel 5?

Comment: Hi Robert. It´s a Pixel 5, yes.

Comment: Maybe, better to contact aaos-on-phone@google.com as described in the doc you mentioned?

Comment: @Wonil Thank you for your suggestion, I sent them an email but I have not received a response from them...